# add node at beginning in c

Tags: c, linked-list

This is my code to add node at beginning.

```
void screate(ll *node)
{
  ll *newNode=(ll *)malloc(sizeof(ll));
  printf("Enter number :\t");
  scanf("%d",&newNode->data);
  if(newNode->data != NULL)
  {
    newNode->next=node;
    node= newNode;
    screate(node);
  }
  else
  {
    free(newNode);
    newNode=NULL;
  }
}
```

Even i found same code [here](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Singly-linked_list/Insertion), I unable to figure out, why I getting wrong output.

This is the current node

**`56->78->77->NULL`**

But, when i'm trying to add new node at the beginning, then still I'm getting same output i.e. **`56->78->77->NULL`**. Need Help !!

**UPDATE**

```
void show(ll *node){
while(node->next != NULL)
 {
  printf("%d->",node->data);
  node=node->next;
 }
printf("NULL");
}
```

Comment: And you don't need that cast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning to `node` which is just a parameter to the function. Since it's passed by value, this won't update the version held by the calling function.

You need to pass a pointer to it instead (i.e. `ll **node`) and change your code to assign to `*node`, and also changer the caller to add a `&` before the argument to take its address.

```
void screate(ll **node)
{
  ll *newNode=malloc(sizeof(ll));
  printf("Enter number :\t");
  scanf("%d",&newNode->data);
  if(newNode->data != NULL)
  {
    newNode->next=*node;
    *node= newNode;
    screate(node);
  }
  else
  {
    free(newNode);
  }
}
```

If you pass a pointer to something to a function, it can change the something but not the pointer itself. The natural conclusion is therefore to make the something itself the pointer - i.e. a pointer to a pointer.

In principle you can take this pointer chaining as deep as you like, but in practice you won't generally need anything more than "pointer to pointer to thing".

Couple of other points. Try to avoid variable names like `l` and `ll` as lowercase L's can easily be confused with the digit 1 (and an uppercase I) in many fonts. Also, your use of a recursive call into `screate()` again would be potentially more efficient as a `while` loop instead. Some compilers will spot that it's [tail-recursive](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and optimise to a loop anyway, but I never like to rely on that sort of thing when it's just as clear to use a loop in the first place.

Comment: do i need to change anything in show function too. Because, it is showing garbage value at beginning

Comment: This change shouldn't affect functions which only read the list, only those that add to the start of it (i.e. replace the first element).

Comment: but i don't know, why it is showing garbage value at beginning. :(

Comment: You appear to be relying on `newNode->data` being `NULL` but `malloc` won't do that for you. Use `calloc` or, better, check the return of `scanf` instead of checking for `NULL` (anything other than 1 indicates a failure of some sort in this particular case). Also, if you're creating a new list make sure the argument is a pointer to a variable which is `NULL` not just a `NULL` itself.

Comment: Also, you should avoid `scanf()` in production code as it can lead to security problems and other bugs. [This blog post](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/index.php/2008/02/07/scanf-and-why-you-should-avoid-using-it/) seems to have a reasonable discussion of the issues.

Comment: Ok, got it, but i have another doubt, whenever I'm adding single node or multiple node. But, it is adding only single node (first one) at the beginning. May I know why ?

Comment: Your `show()` function looks ok except I think it will miss the final element. I suspect the problem is during adding.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> newNode->next=node;
> node = newNode;
> ```

The problem is that `node = newNode` only changes the local copy of `node` which means the caller doesn't see the change. For the caller it's as if you never called the function, `node` still points to wherever it pointed before.

You may want to pass a `ll **node` and change `*node` or something else.

Comment: do i need to change anything in `show` function too. Because, it is showing garbage value at beginning

Comment: @var___ The show function is OK. You probably did the wrong thing when adding.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the signature with parameter as a pointer to linked list pointer

```
void screate(ll **node);
```

And your corresponding pointer changes in your function must be like this

```
newNode->next=*node;
*node= newNode;
screate(&node);
```

Comment: i did, now it is showing some garbage value at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing your screate function so that it returns a `struct ll *`. The return value would correspond to your new head node.

`if(newNode->data != NULL)` is not a sensible way to detect input failures from scanf. In fact, that line of code isn't sensible, period. NULL is identified as a member of the set of null pointers. newNode->data is an int, not a pointer. Comparing it to 0 would make more sense. [Here][1] is a standardised scanf reference. Read it carefully and answer the following questions, and you will know how to distinguish between success and failure of scanf:

```
int x, y;
int z = scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
int c = getchar();
```

1. If I send "abcd{enter}" through stdin, what will z be?
2. If I send "abcd{enter}" through stdin, what will c be?
3. If I send an EOF signal through stdin, what will scanf return?
4. Which value would z be, if it successfully read and put values into the two variables x and y?